# What connector is this on HP 463172-001 fan?

Tags: identification, connector

It's a fan from an HP ProLiant server, what connector does it use?

[image: photo of fan and connector 1]

[image: photo of fan and connector 2]

Comment: google `keyed 6 pin header` and look at the pictures ... you'll see https://protostack.com.au/shop/connectors/idc/idc-male-connector-shrouded-header-6-pin/

Comment: Looks like an IDC male.

Comment: Some generic HE13/HE14 connector… you can probably mate it with most things pitched 2.54; For Molex the C-Grid series IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fan p/n is written right on the fan.

HP just added a different  connector :

- 6pin female keyed header right-angle board to cable 3x2row 0.1” centre to the 4 wire interface.

Probably proprietary.

https://www.delta-fan.com/Download/Spec/PFC0612DE-F00.pdf

12V 40W Delco

Why replace? was it bad or just noisy using a bigger fan?

Comment: don't want to replace it, but want to connect it to a normal consumer psu (perhaps a 4pin molex?), but first i want to know what kind of connector i'm dealing with

Comment: Just make an adapter with a dual row header to 4 wire fan plug to MOBO if you want speed control